# Session timeout not working on Jboss/IBM WAS but working on Tomcat fine

Tags: tomcat, jboss, zk

I have two WARs (A and B) , If I deploy B(it's a zk application) on tomcat and A(Jboss application) on Jboss, after the session time out its redirecting to login page but , if I deploy A and B on Jboss , but on session timeout its staying on same page.

I used custom listener on web.xml(of B.War) which extends HttpSessionListener.

```
<listener>
    <description>
    Used to cleanup when a session is destroyed</description>
    <display-name>ZK Session cleaner</display-name>
    <listener-class>com.CustomListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

The above listener gets called on Tomcat but not Jboss.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: It seems your deployment descriptor file is missing the mapping: <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>comingsoon</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: @FranciscoMelojunior: U mean in the web.xml of B.war? I did add then it's not recogniing the war getting 404 error.

Comment: @FranciscoMelojunior: Below are the mappings I have.
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>